# Finding out which locks that are acquired in a query on SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a SQL statement from my application. I'd like to know which locks that statement acquires; how can I do that with SQL server?
The statement has been involved in a deadlock, which I'm trying to analyze; I cannot reproduce the deadlock.
I'm running on MS SQL Server 2005.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest that you turn on the Deadlock Detection Trace Flags in the first instance, rather than running a Profiler Trace indefinitely.

This way, the event details will be logged to the SQL Server Error Log.

Review the following Books Online reference for details of the various trace flags. You need to use 1204 and/or 1222

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188396(SQL.90).aspx

Be sure to enable the trace flags with server scope and not just the current session. For example use:

```
DBCC TRACEON(1222,-1)
```

Comment: Interesting, how can i set the flags? in a query analyzer?
any overhead involved here?

Comment: I ran both "DBCC TRACEON(1222,-1)" and "DBCC TRACEON(1204 ,-1)" and started a deadlock graph trace (on sql server 2005).  When I forced a deadlock, the trace captured it.  However the there is no record of the deadlock within the SQL Server Error log.  I'm looking in SQL Server Management Studio in the "SQL Server Agent"+"Error Logs"+"Current -"+right click+"View Agent Log" what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You're looking in the wrong logs, those are the agent logs. Management > Sql Server Logs

Comment: @Tomas: As mentioned by Sam, you need to look as the SQL Server Log as opposed to the SQL Server Agent Log.

Comment: @Sam, thank, I found it now.  The info looks to contain about the same (log vs trace xml file), but the xml file is a lot easier to look at.

Answer (score 7):

You can run the statement in a transaction, but not commit the transaction.  Since the locks will be held until the transaction is committed, this gives you time to inspect the locks.  (Not indefinitely, but like 5 minutes by default.)

Like:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
select * from table
```

Then open Management Studio and check the locks.  They're in Management -> Activity Monitor -> Locks by Object or Locks by Process.  After you're done, run:

```
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

to free the locks.

Comment: Great idea! Start transaction but dont commit to get lock detail for given query. If one doesnt have Management studio then simple `SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks' also helps in seeing details about acquired locks.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a query that will show you all active locks, who's got them, and what object they are on.  I pulled this from a technet article or something years and years ago.  It works on SQL 2000 and 2005 (change sysobjects to sys.objects for 2005.)  Uncomment the WHERE clause if you want to restrict it to just this databse, and just the "EXCLUSIVE" locks.

```
select 'Locks' as Locks,
    spid, nt_username, name, hostname, loginame, waittime, open_tran,
    convert(varchar ,getdate() - last_batch, 114) as TimeSinceLastCommand,
    case req_mode
    when  0 then 'Not granted'
    when  1 then 'Schema stability'
    when  2 then 'Schema modification'
    when  3 then 'Intent shared'
    when  4 then 'Shared intent update'
    when  5 then 'Intent shared shared'
    when  6 then 'Intent exclusive'
    when  7 then 'Shared Intent Exclusive'
    when  8 then 'Shared'
    when  9 then 'Update'
    when 10 then 'Intent insert NULL'
    when 11 then 'Intent shared exclusive'
    when 12 then 'Intent update'
    when 13 then 'Intent shared-update'
    when 14 then 'Exclusive'
    when 15 then 'Bulk operation'
    else str(req_mode) end as LockMode
from master..syslockinfo
    left join sysobjects so on so.id = rsc_objid
    left join master..sysprocesses sp on sp.spid = req_spid
--where rsc_dbid = (select db_id()) and ltrim(req_mode) in (6,7,11,14)
```

Comment: Small comment: numbers are a bit different for SQL 2012: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189497.aspx

Answer (score 2):

run a trace in the profiler (pick the blank template), select the deadlock graph event, and on the new tab that appears (Events Extraction Settings), save each (check save deadlock XML events separately) in its own file. Open this file in an xml viewer and it will be easy to tell what is happening.  Each process is contained, with a stack of procedure calls, etc. and all locks are in there too.

Let this trace run until the deadlock happens again, info is only recorded when a deadlock happens, so not much overhead.  If it never happens again, good it is solved, if not you have captured all the info.

Comment: But for doing that I would have to recreate the scenario while running trace? I can't reproduce the scenario.

Comment: whats the overhead of running that trace?

Comment: run this trace in production, or where ever it is happening. If you never see the deadlock again, good do nothing.  if you see it, this will record what happened and then you can figure out what is going on.

Comment: the overhead on a trace can be huge, if you select lots of events (there are events that fire every time each statement in a procedure is executed, another for each time it completes, etc), you can gather gigs of data in a short while.  If you only select the deadlock graph event, you only get data following a deadlock, which I hope is rare on your system.

Comment: Use the Trace Flags rather than a Profiler trace if concerned about performance.

Comment: FYI, We've run the profiler with the deadlock filter on a heavily used production system. It didn't seem to affect performance.

Comment: @KM, this is very good! thanks! I also need this on one of my projects experiencing deadlocks on my production site.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a profiler trace on your dev box for the queries and see exactly what locks are taken. This is typically a huge amount of data, but much of it will be patterns you can skim over. E.g. for read committed isolation, you will see a succession of locks being acquired and released as you do a table or index scan (each row must be locked before it is read, and it is immediately released after it is read).

What isolation do you run under? What kind of queries are deadlocking? Are you using explicit transactions that encompass multiple updates, or are they single statements deadlocking?

The most typical case for a deadlock is a transaction with the sequence (update table x, update table y), and a second transaction with the sequence (update table y, update table x). The common solution is to make sure you use the same update sequence across queries.

Let us know what kind of queries they are, there are different common issues for different types of transactions.

Answer (score -1):

Troubleshooting deadlocks:

http://blogs.msdn.com/bartd/archive/2006/09/09/747119.aspx
http://blogs.msdn.com/bartd/archive/2006/09/13/751343.aspx

Reproducing deadlocks:

http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/01/01/reproducing-deadlocks-involving-only-one-table.aspx